# Chrome developer tools. DOM subtree modification breakpoint?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Will this break-point will only be invoked if nodes in sub-tree is added/removed, and not if they are simply modified?

As testing I tried to add class with JS to sub-tree elements, and the breakpoint did not invoke.

So just want to be sure, that only thing that will trigger this particular break-point is only addition/removal of sub-nodes, and not the modification of any f they're attributes or anything else for that matter, can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subtree modifications are node insertions and removals in the DOM [sub]tree rooted at the given node.

In order to break on the `class` attribute modifications you need to use... know what? `Break on Attribute Modifications`! :-)

Comment: Yeah I know I could use that... I just needed confirmation if its only removals/insertions of nodes, which I now have :)

Comment: To be absolutely sure, check out the source code: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/InspectorDOMDebuggerAgent.cpp (search for `hasBreakpoint(parent, SubtreeModified)`).

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) .... [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42136051/2581562)

Answer (score -1):

I can't add comments to your question, that's why I will post it as a new answer. Take a look here: [how to set DOM Breakpoints in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826916/how-to-set-dom-breakpoints-in-chrome)

In general, open Chrome Developer Tools, select first tab called ***Elements***, then find the element on which you want to put breakpoint, right click on it and a context menu with several options for a breakpoint will be opened. Options are:

1. Break on Subtree Modifications
2. Break on Attribute Modifications
3. Break on Node Removal

Comment: I am aware how to add, and use them. I was a bit confused about what exactly causes the Subtree modification. As if is it only removal/addition of nodes, or is there anything else? Cause adding attributes to sub-elements doesnt seem to invoke it :)