# Chrome - Break on attributes modification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I want to break when the class attribute is changed by a script.

[image]

**I tried it with "Break on: attribute modifications but it doesn't break."**

[image]

Comment: The element might be recreated entirely.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought of too, but shouldn't `node removal` then apply..?

Comment: Now, it works, after page refresh and I have also ticked several different global event listener breakpoints.

Comment: @Legends what global event listener breakpoints did you set? Seems like setting **Attribute Modifications** should be enough for your use case.

Comment: Just checked it again, I ticked off all event listeners, so the page refresh solved it, and yes, only attribute modification is necessary here.

Answer (score 28):

Usually Chrome's `Break on` functionality should work as expected, if not you can use the below:

**Workaround**

The following code will only work if your browser supports [MutationObserver](https://caniuse.com/#search=MutationObserver).
Open developer tools using `F12` and execute the following code in the console:

```
var Spy = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Spy() {
    }
    Spy.observe = function (targetNode) {
        Spy.observer.observe(targetNode, Spy.config);
    };
    Spy.disconnect = function () {
        Spy.observer.disconnect();
    };
    Spy["break"] = function (mutationsList, observer) {
        debugger;
    };
    Spy.config = { attributes: true, childList: true }; // Change the config to your needs
    Spy.observer = new MutationObserver(Spy["break"]);
    return Spy;
}());
```

After that you have to watch the node that you want to track changes for, like:

```
Spy.observe(document.getElementById("notify-container"));
```

Now the debugger will break on attribute changes made to this element.The developer tools must stay open for this to work.

When the debugger breaks, you can now under `Sources` tab see, which function made the change:

[image]

To stop tracking use:

```
Spy.disconnect();
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: what if this is on load that a script modify the target ?

Comment: @Matoeil You could use Fiddler to modify the page before it gets parsed by the browser, for example: https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse#modifying-a-request-or-response

Comment: @Legends Unfortunately this doesn't show me the function responsible for the change, I can only see the Spy.break in the call stack. I thought this might be the case as the mutationObserver is not directly called by the responsible code, but it just raises an event in the event loop.