# How do find which script is functioning on a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I am trying to find a way to automate a process. I want to download pictures from a specific site. When you scroll down the page, more thumbnails appear with href tags to the actual image. Is there anyway to find out which script is creating the attributes?

Comment: You really need to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a break point at element sub-tree modification (in chrome devtools). Look at those answers:
[Chrome developer tools. DOM subtree modification breakpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933301/chrome-developer-tools-dom-subtree-modification-breakpoint)