# Suggestion & Tips to debug the browser on specific state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Is there a solution to debug a browser on specific state ?

Introducing an example:

I want to use `typeahead.js` along with twitter bootstrap 3, but there are no styles available for that plugin. So I wish to style it by using a **Google Chrome DevTool (F12)**.

When I start typing, there is a floating block which appears with suggestions, i want to do a Right-Click on it and inspect its elements, but whenever I do my Right-Click, that content dissappears.

And here comes the question - can I freeze a browser so it won't let the js to do it's job, therefore I could inspect that floating window ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can right click on the element in the DOM tree and force the element state. 
[See :hover state in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515124/see-hover-state-in-chrome-developer-tools)

you could also set a dom breakpoint: 
[how to set DOM Breakpoints in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826916/how-to-set-dom-breakpoints-in-chrome)

you could also place a breakpoint in the code: 
[Set a javascript breakpoint in code - in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050465/set-a-javascript-breakpoint-in-code-in-chrome)

or a js breakpoint: 
http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/05/the-three-ways-of-setting-breakpoints-in-javascript/