# From where the select tag appears cant find his source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem**: 
When view goes max width 767px, my menu goes to mobile view. I am practicing this site. But I tried a lot, I couldn't figure out from *where the select tag portion come out in during mobile view time*.

• In source page, it is not there. But in DOM tree its here.
• In normal case it stays `display: none` but in mobile view time, it becomes `display: block`.

But where from this select tag comes? How can I figure out his source?

[image: here is my screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried looking at any other file you may be using? It's probably a script that is dynamically adding elements. You should probably get a better IDE with a find/replace function.

Comment: It’s a difficult question to decipher, even more so without code.  If I’m understanding your problem correctly you can use chrome to find out what is manipulating the Dom.  See this question on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826916/how-to-set-dom-breakpoints-in-chrome.

Comment: If it's live site. Please share that URL here. Someone will definitely help you to solve this.

Comment: I noticce that you are using Superfish for your menu. Is this a Drupal site by any chance? Some Googling tells me that the Superfish module for Drupal has a smallscreen plugin that sounds as if it generates a `<select>` version of a menu at small screen sizes. This is an old-school way of handling menus at narrow screen widths. Source: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151391/why-do-i-get-a-select-dropdown-when-in-mobile-view-from-superfish

Comment: @JonathanNicol I think you got the point. how did you understand, i am using superfish for the menu? yes, probably it was a WordPress site. I downloaded it.  I am making it now as a simple PHP file. I made a php file where the menu part only kept, then i include it to the main page. What can i do ? actually, its killing my long time.