# How to programmatically add HTML DOM breakpoints in chromium?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, chromium

I've seen from this [post about Chromium DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom) that there exists the possibility to add DOM breakpoints. Given that I've a full range of elements to monitor I was trying to find a way to programmatically add such breakpoints. I also read this [question about DOM breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826916/how-to-set-dom-breakpoints-in-chrome) but it doesn't seem to give me any useful hint.

To achieve a similar result I've used to instrument the `setAttribute()` function of such DOM elements replacing it with a wrapper that uses the debugger; instruction to trigger the debugger. Anyway this approach fails when dealing with `innerHTML` or `innerText` assignments given that there is no way of achieving operator overloading in js.

Can someone suggest me a practical solution?

Comment: It would be great if someone has an answer to this! As DOM sometimes gets deleted by some script - and doing a debugger; on a MutationObserver doesn't really help - as that breakpoint does not have the call stack of who triggered it

Comment: This is definetly possible with usind DevtoolsOverDevtools, and may be found by debugging `oncontentmenu` of Elements pane. How exactly to do that I don't know yet

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you trying to do or solve?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe), to observe for any change to a DOM at given root element. Also you can put debugger there and if devTools is open it should break.

```js
const targetNode = document.getElementById('observed-element');
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
    console.log(mutation.target);
    debugger; 
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// change class
setTimeout(()=>{
  targetNode.setAttribute('class', 'some-class')
}, 0);

// change innerText
setTimeout(()=>{
  targetNode.innerText = 'some text';  
}, 0);
```

```html
<div id="observed-element">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open Devtools-Over-Devtools and get references to instances of [DOMModel](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/581bfa00fd962837c51e2284dc78303446088c67/front_end/core/sdk/DOMModel.ts#1005) and [DOMDebuggerModel](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/581bfa00fd962837c51e2284dc78303446088c67/front_end/core/sdk/DOMDebuggerModel.ts#193)

```
// open Devtools (Ctrl+Shift+I)
// open DevtoolsOverDevtools (Ctrl+Shift+I in Devtools)
// open sdk.js from Ctrl+P pane
// set breakpoint in function setDOMBreakpoint(e, t)
// set HTML breakpoint in Devtools to pause on the created breakpoint 

// inside setDOMBreakpoint(e, t)
window.domModel = e.domModel()
window.domDebuggerModel = this

// resume execution, disable breakpoint
_k = [...domModel.idToDOMNode.keys()][0]
_a = await domModel.querySelectorAll(_k, 'div')
_b = _a.map(e => domModel.idToDOMNode.get(e)).filter(Boolean)
_b.map(e => domDebuggerModel.setDOMBreakpoint(e, 'node-removed'))
// 'subtree-modified' | 'attribute-modified' | 'node-removed'

// now all elements are breakpointed
```

Comment: @joão-antunes could you feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.DEBUG = true; // toggles programmatic debugging
```

flag with a global check debug function, like so:

```
window.CHECK_DEBUG = function() {
  if (window.DEBUG) { debugger; } 
}
```

And then insert the following in any function you’re concerned about debugging:

```
   function foo() {
  CHECK_DEBUG();
// foo's usual procedure ...
}
```

To take this a step further (and to take a page out of Firebug's `debug()` and `undebug()` wrapper functions) you can decorate the native JavaScript Function object like so:

```
Function.prototype.debug = function(){   
   var fn = this;
   return function(){     
       if (window.DEBUG) { debugger; } 
       return fn.apply(this, arguments);     
   }; 
};
```

Then you can dynamically debug any function by calling:

```
foo = foo.debug();
```